# How to disable effects on "win key" menu?

Tags: menu, appmenu

To answer my question - please, try this yourslef first, it's easy. Please, press your [Win] key on Ubuntu (I have 18.04 LTS), and see what happens. (FX would happens, and 7/10 times mine PC would hang, due to HW failure). Then you(if you were me with faulty GPU, or CPU) may think - how can you disable animated effects and transparency (which puts extra load and some day could hang your GPU/CPU/.. whatever it could - too! Because it just shows that it could hang up currently (on my old machine), and I dont manage to examine/replace old HW. It may work, but because of FX it could not!!!

So this thing is LIKELY(not always, but 7 of 10 times) hangs PC up. And I am looking forr solution to disable it, while I can still use the menu.

What does happens when this menu pops up? And how to uncode these FX effects back to simplicity and low power consumption (Effects like transparency/animations and other heavy CPU-GPU rendering interaction, and whatever they coded, but not actually needed for most desktop PCs)?

These effects would hang PC when I am trying to switch language but mistyped and pressed just Win key on the keyboars, so that menu poops up and hangs the PC. Also when I am in need to find newly installed app - this is a trouble! (approximately 7 reboots until I am able to send shortcut or add it to Favs)

---

PS (Emotional!)

I have pretty old hardware like i7 920 plus R9 390, and some circuits has broken inside old hardware. All works fine, except something. This can be reproduced like pressing win key, when this fancy transparent shit pops up and pulls in installed app icons. This shit would happen when you're trying to press Win+Space combo but somehow human-fail to press simultaneously (often hunam-case)

Sorry for this "bad" word, but it is related to my oppinion that PC may easily dwarf up beautiful interface, yet remaining productive, not wasting cycles for transitions and so on. So I am protagonist of CPU/GPU-heavy effects (FORCED BY OS! are you win or osx!?), like when it comes to push smooth scroll and so on. Ima like crying "HEY you re doing it to every End-User PC!!! Stop spreading cancer! Let user initially select between productivity and beauty of GFX..." But that's probably installer's question, not mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu uses Gnome Shell, which relies on and requires graphics acceleration to render its desktop effects. You can turn animations off and see whether this removes the issue. An easy way to do this is to run following terminal command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false
```

If you feel the desktop is still slow, then move to another desktop that does not require graphics acceleration, such as xfce (Xubuntu) or Mate (Ubuntu Mate).

To restore the animation setting to default, issue the command:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations
```